# Numpy reshape 1d to 2d array with 1 column

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

In `numpy` the dimensions of the resulting array vary at run time.
There is often confusion between a 1d array and a 2d array with 1 column.
In one case I can iterate over the columns, in the other case I cannot.

How do you solve elegantly that problem?
To avoid littering my code with `if` statements checking for the dimensionality, I use this function:

```
def reshape_to_vect(ar):
    if len(ar.shape) == 1:
      return ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],1)
    return ar
```

However, this feels inelegant and costly. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What is the `dtype`?  Looks `structured`.

Comment: It's irrelevant, I just used that as an example of how I could end up with 1d or 2d array. My question is about how to convert elegantly 1d to 2d array systematically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do -

```
ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],-1)
```

That second input to `reshape` : `-1` takes care of the number of elements for the second axis. Thus, for a `2D` input case, it does no change. For a `1D` input case, it creates a `2D` array with all elements being "pushed" to the first axis because of  `ar.shape[0]`, which was the total number of elements.

**Sample runs**

1D Case :

```
In [87]: ar
Out[87]: array([ 0.80203158,  0.25762844,  0.67039516,  0.31021513,  0.80701097])

In [88]: ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],-1)
Out[88]: 
array([[ 0.80203158],
       [ 0.25762844],
       [ 0.67039516],
       [ 0.31021513],
       [ 0.80701097]])
```

2D Case :

```
In [82]: ar
Out[82]: 
array([[ 0.37684126,  0.16973899,  0.82157815,  0.38958523],
       [ 0.39728524,  0.03952238,  0.04153052,  0.82009233],
       [ 0.38748174,  0.51377738,  0.40365096,  0.74823535]])

In [83]: ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],-1)
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0.37684126,  0.16973899,  0.82157815,  0.38958523],
       [ 0.39728524,  0.03952238,  0.04153052,  0.82009233],
       [ 0.38748174,  0.51377738,  0.40365096,  0.74823535]])
```

Comment: A variant of this answer is: `x = np.reshape(x, (len(x),-1))`, which also deals with the case when the input is a 1d or 2d list.

Comment: @LucaCiti make this a separate answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 51):

The simplest way:

```
ar.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: The simplest method ever, works in hstack when adding new column to matrix

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the need to reshape in the first place, if you slice a row / column with a list, or a "running" slice, you will get a 2D array with one row / column

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(np.random.normal(size=(4,4)))
print x, '\n'

Result:
[[ 0.01360395  1.12130368  0.95429414  0.56827029]
 [-0.66592215  1.04852182  0.20588886  0.37623406]
 [ 0.9440652   0.69157556  0.8252977  -0.53993904]
 [ 0.6437994   0.32704783  0.52523173  0.8320762 ]] 

y = x[:,[0]]
print y, 'col vector \n'
Result:
[[ 0.01360395]
 [-0.66592215]
 [ 0.9440652 ]
 [ 0.6437994 ]] col vector 


y = x[[0],:]
print y, 'row vector \n'

Result:
[[ 0.01360395  1.12130368  0.95429414  0.56827029]] row vector 

# Slice with "running" index on a column
y = x[:,0:1]
print y, '\n'

Result:
[[ 0.01360395]
 [-0.66592215]
 [ 0.9440652 ]
 [ 0.6437994 ]]
```

Instead if you use a single number for choosing the row/column, it will result in a 1D array, which is the root cause of your issue:

```
y = x[:,0]
print y, '\n'

Result:
[ 0.01360395 -0.66592215  0.9440652   0.6437994 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

A variant of  the answer by divakar is: `x = np.reshape(x, (len(x),-1))`, which also deals with the case when the input is a 1d or 2d list.

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two ways to go from 1 dimensional array (N) to 2 dimensional
array with 1 column
(N x 1):

1. Indexing with [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis);
2. Reshape with `reshape()` method.

```py
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])  # shape: (3,) <- 1d

x[:, None]               # shape: (3, 1) <- 2d (single column matrix)
x[:, np.newaxis]         # shape: (3, 1) <- a meaningful alias to None

x.reshape(-1, 1)         # shape: (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked about `dtype` because your example is puzzling.

I can make a structured array with 3 elements (1d) and 3 fields:

```
In [1]: A = np.ones((3,), dtype='i,i,i')
In [2]: A
Out[2]: 
array([(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

I can access one field by name (adding brackets doesn't change things)

```
In [3]: A['f0'].shape
Out[3]: (3,)
```

but if I access 2 fields, I still get a 1d array

```
In [4]: A[['f0','f1']].shape
Out[4]: (3,)
In [5]: A[['f0','f1']]
Out[5]: 
array([(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Actually those extra brackets do matter, if I look at values

```
In [22]: A['f0']
Out[22]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [23]: A[['f0']]
Out[23]: 
array([(1,), (1,), (1,)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4')])
```

If the array is a simple 2d one, I still don't get your shapes

```
In [24]: A=np.ones((3,3),int)
In [25]: A[0].shape
Out[25]: (3,)
In [26]: A[[0]].shape
Out[26]: (1, 3)
In [27]: A[[0,1]].shape
Out[27]: (2, 3)
```

But as to question of making sure an array is 2d, regardless of whether the indexing returns 1d or 2, your function is basically ok

```
def reshape_to_vect(ar):
    if len(ar.shape) == 1:
      return ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],1)
    return ar
```

You could test `ar.ndim` instead of `len(ar.shape)`.  But either way it is not costly - that is, the execution time is minimal - no big array operations.  `reshape` doesn't copy data (unless your strides are weird), so it is just the cost of creating a new array object with a shared data pointer.

Look at the code for `np.atleast_2d`; it tests for 0d and 1d.  In the 1d case it returns `result = ary[newaxis,:]`.  It adds the extra axis first, the more natural `numpy` location for adding an axis.  You add it at the end.

`ar.reshape(ar.shape[0],-1)` is a clever way of bypassing the `if` test.  In small timing tests it faster, but we are talking about microseconds, the effect of a function call layer.

`np.column_stack` is another function that creates column arrays if needed.  It uses:

```
 if arr.ndim < 2:
        arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the example. I was trying to give a concrete example, but if it's confusing, it's better not to have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = np.array(12)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
print(y.shape)

O/P:- (1, 1)
```